# Why is Eclipse running with a particular JRE when I'm specifically telling it to run with a particular JDK?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-7

Windows 7, Eclipse Oxygen 1a.

From a command prompt, I have the following:

```
>set JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152
```

In my eclipse.ini file, I have this as the first line:

```
-vm C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_152/bin/javaw.exe
```

In C:\Program Files\Java I have both "jdk1.8.0_152" and "jre1.8.0_144".

When I start Eclipse, I see the following at the top of my workspace/.metadata/.log file:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.7.1.M20171009-0410
java.version=1.8.0_144
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -vm C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_152/bin/javaw.exe -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -vm C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_152/bin/javaw.exe -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
```

And when I inspect the process with jvisualvm, I see the following:

```
Java: version 1.8.0_144, vendor Oracle Corporation
Java Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144
```

What is causing Eclipse to still use the 1.8.0_144 JRE?  This is causing me a problem because I have a Gradle build that needs to get the tools.jar from the JDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are putting it on the FIRST line on your .ini file.

> The -vm option must occur after the other Eclipse-specific options
>   (such as -product, --launcher.*, etc), but before the -vmargs option,
>   since everything after -vmargs is passed directly to the JVM.

Check this and other recomendations on the section Specifying the JVM here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini